# Controlling SqlConnection Timeouts

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# application that updates processing values every second, and updates the mssql database and an OPC server, if I lose connection to the server (which hosts the OPC and the database) I start storing the process values offline until I get the connection back then update the OPC, however I am running into MSSQL Server timeout issues which causes the client machine to freeze while connection is lost, and therefore losing process values from being stored to the OPC. I tried set the Sql connection and SqlCommand timeout to 5 seconds but without any luck, I think I am timing out on TCP connection to SQL.

How would you solve this issue? I even used the asynchronous call for my functions calls to the database but without real improvements.

the link below helped me a bit but still not great:
http://improve.dk/controlling-sqlconnection-timeouts/

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks